# Control access to app resources with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

Let's say we have a web app that lets the user create "widgets". We have a new client that would like to control access to each widget with their organization's Active Directory, such that some of their users can view certain widgets and other users can edit other widgets.

What's the proper way to implement this? Should every widget have its own read group and modify group, and we let the client control the membership to these groups? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Design discussions can be long-lasting and people nowadays prefer Agile methodology to keep making changes as per the new requirements to get the end refined product.

But, here is a one way in which you can implement this -

- You will have one B2C(for new users) Login and one AD login(for organization users).
- Then, you will have to use RBAC to have different views and features for different types of users(one B2C, 2 different users from AD) using claims and [user properties for AD users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/customize-application-attributes). For eg, [Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.co.in/) has same website but different experiences for hosts and Users who book stays.